# Python Pandas Dataframe aggregated group by functions

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe, outliers

I have a function to detect and remove outliers from an experiment data. 
I want to apply this function on my data, stored in a data frame. However, the data frame consists many experiment subjects and 4 experiment conditions, while the outlier detection function should be applied on the level and for each  subject + trialcode.
This is how my data looks like:

```
                  subject     trialcode    correct  latency
           0    1790361018         nonsn        1     4051
           1    1790361018     neighbour        1     1266
           2    1790361018     neighbour        1     2145
           3    1790361018         nonsn        0     2959
           4    1790361018  nonneighbour        1     1086
           5    1790361018      nonwords        1     2956
           6    1790361018      nonwords        1     3814
           7    1790361018  nonneighbour        1     4924
           8    1790361018      nonwords        0     4771
           9    1790361018  nonneighbour        0     2654
           10   1790361018     neighbour        1      945
           11   1790361018  nonneighbour        1     1189
           12   1790361018     neighbour        1     1215
           13   1790361018     neighbour        1      800
           14   1790361018     neighbour        1      752
           15   1790361018     neighbour        1      963
           16   1790361018     neighbour        1     1822
           17   1790361018  nonneighbour        1      856
           18   1790361018  nonneighbour        1      695
           19   1790361018      nonwords        1     2020
           20   1790361018     neighbour        1     1303
           21   1790361018  nonneighbour        1     1597
           22   1790361018      nonwords        1     1327
           23   1790361018     neighbour        1     1084
           24   1790361018     neighbour        1     2434
           25   1790361018  nonneighbour        1      917
           26   1790361018     neighbour        1     1170
           27   1790361018      nonwords        0     1388
           28   1790361018      nonwords        1     1871
           29   1790361018     neighbour        1      967
```

This is the ourlier function:

```
 def reject_outliers(data, m=2):
    return data[abs(data - np.mean(data)) < m * np.std(data)]
```

Is there a way to apply this function on groups of subject+trialcode ?